# Predictable process generates a linear space

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory

Suppose that $\Omega$ is a finite probability space

$$
\Omega=\left\{\omega_1,...,\omega_m\right\}.
$$

Hence any random variable $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ can be expressed as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$

$$
Y(\omega)=\left(\begin{array}{c}Y(\omega_1)\\
Y(\omega_2)\\
\vdots\\
Y(\omega_m)
\end{array}\right).
$$

Let $r_t$ be a $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted process and let $\alpha_t$ be a predictable process with $t=1,...,T$. Define

$$
G(\alpha,r) = \sum_{t=1}^T\alpha_t\,r_t.
$$

Consider the space

$$
\mathcal{L} = \left\{G(\alpha,r)\mid\alpha\text{ is predictable}\right\}\subset\mathbb{R}^m.
$$

I need to prove that $\mathcal{L}$ is a linear space. Clearly the predictability of $\alpha$ is fundamental. In fact, if predictability implies that $\alpha_t$ does not depend on $\omega$ the proof is immediate since

$$
\mathcal{L} = \left\{\alpha_1\,\left(\begin{array}{c}r_1(\omega_1)\\
r_1(\omega_2)\\
\vdots\\
r_1(\omega_m)
\end{array}\right)+...+\alpha_T\,\left(\begin{array}{c}r_T(\omega_1)\\
r_T(\omega_2)\\
\vdots\\
r_T(\omega_m)
\end{array}\right)\right\}=\text{span}\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}r_1(\omega_1)\\
r_1(\omega_2)\\
\vdots\\
r_1(\omega_m)
\end{array}\right),...,\left(\begin{array}{c}r_T(\omega_1)\\
r_T(\omega_2)\\
\vdots\\
r_T(\omega_m)
\end{array}\right)\right).
$$

Nevertheless I am not sure that predictability means independence from $\omega\in\Omega$. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Sums of predictable processes are predictable and so are scalar multiples.

Comment: It is not exactly a sum of predictable processes since $r_t$ is adapted, not predictable.

Comment: But $r$ is fixed so let $\alpha, \beta$ be predictable processes, then $G(\alpha, r) + G(\beta, r) = G(\alpha + \beta, r)$ is in $\mathcal{L}$ since $\alpha + \beta$ is predictable.

Comment: Ok, thanks, you are perfectly right.